# Maven not passing -D commandline arguments to my archetype post-processing goal

Tags: maven, archetypes, mojo, post-processing

I have a v2.2 maven archetype that runs fine and after it is completed, I want to perform some post-processing on the project it drops on the file system. I accomplish this by using the -Dgoals commandline option as follows:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=buildtools-archetype-resources \
   -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
   -DarchetypeCatalog=local \
   -DgroupId=net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev \
   -DartifactId=bt-converter-test \
   -Dpackage=net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev \
   -Dgoals=net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev:buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch \
   -DbtBasedir=/ccs_home/projects/CCSSC/SC_Inventory
```

The buildtools-archetype-resources archetype runs fine. And Maven indeed is invoking the touch plugin post-processing goal as expected. However, what maven is not doing is passing along the -DbtBasedir System property (none of the System properties for that matter) to the forked jvm it invokes to run that post processing goal.

Here is the output from the archetype generation phase:

```
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: buildtools-archetype-resources:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: bt-converter-test
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: net/jpmchase/cma/cmadev
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev
[INFO] Parameter: btBasedir, Value: /ccs_home/projects/CCSSC/SC_Inventory
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: bt-converter-test
[INFO] project created from Archetype in dir: C:\ds\workspaces\bt-converter-test
```

As you can see during the archetype generation phase, Maven is getting all the System properties setup as properties, including the btBasedir System property.

I am using maven 3.1.1. I debugged the maven-archetype-plugin v2.2 source code and can see that the maven archetype commandline System properties are not being transferred to the forked maven jvm that runs the post-processing goal.

Here is the value of the commandline that is built which is used to invoke the post-processing goal:

```
cmd.exe /X /C "C:\ds\ds_env\tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn.bat -B net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev:buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch"
```

This was taken straight out of my debugger with the breakpoint on line 102 of org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.java:

```
(line 102 --->) int exitCode = executeCommandLine( cli, request );
```

In my touch Mojo, I have this private member variable to accept the btBasedir property:

```
/**
 * The Buildtools btBasedir.
 */
@Parameter
private String btBasedir;
```

At the start of the `execute()` method, I dump-out the value of the btBasedir property:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    getLog().info("Starting Buildtools to Maven project migration......");
    try {
        getLog().info("New Maven project base directory [" + project.getBasedir() + "]");
        getLog().info("Source Buildtools project base directory [" + btBasedir + "]");
    .
    .
    .
```

The console output from this looks like:

```
[INFO] Invoking post-archetype-generation goals: net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev:buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bt-converter-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch (default-cli) @ bt-converter-test ---
[INFO] Starting Buildtools to Maven project migration......
[INFO] New Maven project base directory [C:\ds\workspaces\bt-converter-test]
[INFO] Source Buildtools project base directory [null]
```

As you can see, the btBasedir is not getting carried from the mvn archetype:generate commandline.

```
Source Buildtools project base directory [null]
```

Any ideas on whether this is possible or have I missed something that will allow this transfer of System properties to occur?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's causing problems is as follows:

```
-Dgoals=net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev:buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch \
-DbtBasedir=/ccs_home/projects/CCSSC/SC_Inventory
```

What's happening is that the "-DbtBasedir" is being passed into the Maven archetype plugin, instead of being part of the longer -Dgoals"..." string.

Change your command as follows:

```
-Dgoals='net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev:buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch -DbtBasedir=/ccs_home/projects/CCSSC/SC_Inventory'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Intersting thought - tried it, but what happened was that the -Dgoals System property had a value of "'-Dgoals=net.jpmchase.cma.cmadev:buildtools-converter-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch ". Notice how the first single-quote was part of the String, but the value I passed on the command-line was lopped-off after that space character. Everything after that was truncted and didn't come through. So....still diggin.

Comment: So, quickly tried using double-quotes rather than single quotes. And that allows the full value to come through, not truncated. However, still had the same result. The problem there is that the code in the maven archetype plugin splits the -Dgoals System property at all commas, in-case there are multiple post-processing goals. In my case, I just pass one goal. But sneaking-in the extra System property doesn't get picked-up and passed-along to the forked jvm :-(

Comment: Another option is to try putting the goals into pom file instead of passing it in on the command line.  The XML brackets avoid the confusion around quotes, whitespace, etc.